# Symfony2 - Using getArrayResult() results in a missing field from db

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

Can use some guidance on this--some context, I am adding a simple pagination code to a simple blog I'm practicing on, however when using getArrayResult() from the pagination, it's missing a field ('comments') which I need passed into my twig file.

When using getRepository (to get all) it works fine with the 'comments' field being returned as desired. Comments is it's own table separate from blog. Is there any way I can get this working with the way the pagination has been setup?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

The comments field is setup as a 'one to many' for my blog entity.

**Blog entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="blog")
 */
protected $comments;
```

**Comment entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Blog", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $blog;
```

**Controller getRepository**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$blogs = $em->getRepository('GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog')
    ->getLatestBlogs();
```

**Pagination code**

```
    $page = $request->get('page');

    $count_per_page = 5;
    $total_count = $this->getTotalBlogs();
    $total_pages = ceil($total_count/$count_per_page);

    if (!is_numeric($page)) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = floor($page);
    }

    if ($total_count <= $count_per_page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if (($page * $count_per_page) > $total_count) {
        $page = $total_pages;
    }

    $offset = 0;

    if ($page > 1) {
        $offset = $count_per_page * ($page - 1);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b')
        ->from('GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog', 'b')
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($count_per_page);

    $blogFinalQuery = $blogQuery->getQuery();

    $blogPage = $blogFinalQuery->getArrayResult();
```

**Dump of repository (where comments is returned)**

```
object(stdClass)[875]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'General\SymProjectBundle\Entity\Blog' (length=36)
  public 'id' => int 2
  public 'title' => string 'Another blog post' (length=17)
  public 'author' => string 'KK' (length=2)
  public 'blog' => string '...' (length=...)
  public 'image' => string 'practice.jpg' (length=12)
  public 'tags' => string 'symfony, php, blog, dummy text, fantasy, features, symproject' (length=61)
  public 'comments' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
  public 'created' => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
  public 'updated' => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
  public 'slug' => string 'another-blog-post' (length=17)
```

**Dump of pagination (missing comments field)**

```
'id' => int 2
  'title' => string 'Another blog post' (length=17)
  'author' => string 'KK' (length=2)
  'blog' => string '... (length=...)
  'image' => string 'practice.jpg' (length=12)
  'tags' => string 'symfony, php, blog, dummy text, fantasy, features, symproject' (length=61)
  'created' => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
  'updated' => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
  'slug' => string 'another-blog-post' (length=17)
```

**Index.html.twig**

```
{# src/General/SymProjectBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'GeneralSymProjectBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{% for blog in blogPage %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
                <div class="blog-post">


                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ blog.title }}</h2>
                        <p class="blog-post-meta"><time datetime="{{ blog.created|date('c') }}">{{ blog.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}</time> by <a href="#">{{ blog.author }}</a></p>

                    <div class="comment">
                        <p><small>Comments: {{ blog.comments|length }}</small></p>
                    </div>

                        <p>{{ blog.blog|truncate(350, true) }}</p><br>

                    <div class="tags">
                        <p><strong>Tags: </strong><span class="highlight">{{ blog.tags }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                        <p class="continue"><a href="{{ path('general_sym_project_show', { 'id': blog.id, 'slug': blog.slug }) }}">More reading&raquo </a></p>
                    <hr>

                </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
{{ parent() }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What tells this command : app/console doctrine:schema:validate ? Is your schema OK ?

Comment: [Mapping] OK - The mapping files are correct. [Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files. It's not a problem with the schema it's how I'm calling the data and it's not liking the relational table data for 'comments' when using getArrayResult(), trying a way to do this with the current pagination setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing commments is a separate table with blog id as a foreign key. Adding this to the pagination code may get the comments for your blogpost.

```
foreach $blogPage as $blog{
  $blog_id = $blog["id"] // U might have to modify these based on the result you get.
  $commentRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('GeneralSymProjectBundle:Comment'');

  $comments []= $repository->findByBlogId($blog_id);
}
```

Pass the comments as a separate variable and try this for the twig:

```
{% block body %}
    {% for blog in blogPage %}
                      .
                      .

                <div class="comment">
                    <p><small>Comments: {{ comments[loop.index0]|length }}</small></p>
                            {% for comment in  comments[loop.index0] %}
                                 //display the comments here if you need
                            {% endfor %}
                 </div>
                      .
                      .
                      .

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html for more on doctrine filtering

Comment: Yes, comments is a separate table with blog_id as a foreign key.

Comment: Not working. Getting the following error "ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: blogId in" and when I tried to use $blog["blog_id"].

Comment: Prior to this I do a dump on $blog and it's giving the same result without the comment field and no blog_id.

Comment: Check the structure of $blog array and use the field which has the blog id to get blog id into $blog_id . I have edited. Try now

Comment: Ok, I've added the modification to the end of the pagination code after $blogPage = $blogFinalQuery->getArrayResult(); and dumped it, it gives a list of the comments, but how do I pass this ($comments[]) in to twig? I'm already using blogPage for the for loop that generates the blogs and pagination code. I've posted the twig file for illustration and the problematic area is {{ blog.comments|length }} which obviously receives no value with getArrayResult().

Comment: Pass $comments as a separate variable to the twig, and you should be able to get the corresponding comments inside the loop using loop.index0 . And then show the comment. For length you can use comments[loop.index0]|length. check http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Comment: Can you explain the loop using loop.index0 or show an example? I've tried to pass it in as {{ comments.comments|length }} and got the following error: (Key "comments" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" does not exist in GeneralSymProjectBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 17) I passed it in from the controller as ('comments' => $comments,).

Comment: Ok trying this Comments: {{ comments|loop.index0|length }} gives me the following error: Key "5" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" does not exist in GeneralSymProjectBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 17. The intention of the comments here if it's unclear is just to show -- Comments: 4 or whatever, to preview of how many comments are in the specific blog post.

Comment: Check the count of blogPage and comments..It should be equal..If you just want to show the number of comments you can modify the query to get just the count too.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following, the $count_per_page is set to 5, for 5 blog posts per page. How does this relate to the error regarding the comments? Evidently, it's not pulling in the total number of comments assigned to a specific blog post.

Comment: It is pulling the 5 comments. Thats why the indexes  "0, 1, 2, 3, 4". Either  {{ comments|loop.index0|length }} is not working or try  {{ comments|loop.index0 -1 |length }}

Comment: Odd, it's working now...not sure why it didn't work before using {{ comments[loop.index0]|length }}. Thank you Manoj for your time and patience in showing me the workaround. Appreciate it sir!

Answer (score 0):

You will not get relational table's data if you use getArrayResult.

This will sure work for you.

```
$blogQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b, c')
        ->from('GeneralSymProjectBundle:Blog', 'b')
        ->leftJoin('b.Comments', 'c');
```

Comment: Testing this out and I get the following error when I do a dump - "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 69 near 'c': Error: Class General\SymProjectBundle\Entity\Blog has no association named Comments"

Comment: Correction changed b.Comments to b.comments and I get a successful dump but when I add in ->setFirstResult($offset) and ->setMaxResults($count_per_page) I'm now limited to only 2 rows from the db??

Comment: To clarify it does give me what I'm looking for yet, as mentioned above but as a caveat it doesn't play nice with the pagination and limits my posts to 2 instead of 5 as set in the max limit.